# Unable to provide the rating feature

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to provide rating feature in my app but when I click on `rate` its says, "Requested item not found".

Comment: You must have a nickname assigned to your Google account in order to review apps. :-)

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiastic No I haven't.

Comment: if it is working for facebook. It should work for your app also. try using getPackageName() intead of giving package name manually .

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code

```
    private void rateAppOnPlayStore() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
    Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    try {
        startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to find google play app.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This will work for `Market` app also.

Comment: If I am able to rate the other app just by changing the package name, I guess it can't be the problem with the code. Moreover your code does the same work.

Comment: Is your app listed in playstore

Comment: Yes, its there. I am trying to include the rating feature in the new version.

Comment: What is current output...error..or is it going to play store app

Comment: Does not give any error, searches for a couple of seconds and says, "The requested item could not be found".

Comment: can you tell me your package name

Comment: Do You know package name is case sensitive

Comment: :Yes, I do. The least you expect of me is to know my app's package name.

Comment: Its com.xxx.xxx
You know I cann't tell you that :p

Comment: :Don't mind. But how do I get out of this trouble. Could there be something that I missed out while uploading the previous version?

Comment: Did you try "http: //play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx.xxx" within your try block instead of "market://details?id="

Comment: @ KarthikPalanivelu Yes I have. THis takes me directly to the playstore but via the browser which I guess is not the appropriate way.